# 0xC0000008: An invalid handle was specified in Hololens 2 using NetQM

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, zeromq, hololens

I'm trying to send some data to a Python server through a [ZMQ Socket](https://zeromq.org/languages/python/). The Python server creates a socket using ZMQ as well.

````
```lang-python
print("Connecting with Unity Toolkit...")
context = zmq.Context()
socket = context.socket(zmq.REP)
socket.bind('tcp://*:5555')

while True:
    request = socket.recv_multipart()
    print("Somethings received");
    req = json.loads(request[1])
    print("Received from Unity Toolkit: ", req)
```
````

I've tried to communicate with that server using a Python ZMQ client and it works, but when I try to do it with the .NET ZMQ library inside of an Unity 3D project, there is an exception that I don't know how to handle. The NETQMClient I was given (this is legacy code from an older project, but I'm allowed to change it) does something like this:

````
```lang-csharp
//this lines are executed using a Thread()
AsyncIO.ForceDotNet.Force();

requestSocket = new RequestSocket();
requestSocket.Connect("tcp://192.162.0.104:5555");

isAvailable = true;
while (!clientStopped){
      //Debug.Log("Continuing");
}

requestSocket.Close();
NetMQConfig.Cleanup();
//end of the function running on a thread
//...
//later, when a button is pressed
try {
    //endpoint is a one-character string that 
    //the server uses as a cue for something   
    requestSocket.SendMoreFrame(endpoint);   
    requestSocket.SendFrame(request); //this a class turned into a JSON using JsonUtility.ToJson
} catch (System.Exception) {
    Debug.Log("Something went wrong");
    throw;
}
```
````

Later the C# script waits for a response and I handle that response and use it. The thing is that I've tested it running the client and the server in the same computer and it works. HOWEVER, when I deploy the project into the real Hololens 2 (where the NETQM client runs), I get this error in Visual Studio.

[image]

I added the try catch block to see if there was some strange behaviour but there is no Exception in that point. Any hints on the right directions are appreciated.

EDIT: Whole Scripts used in this project for replicating the bug.

This class holds the data that will later be converted to JSON

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public static class Serialization {
    public int numPanels;
    public bool colorHarmony;
    public float colorfulness;

 [Serializable]
 public Request(int numPanels, bool colorHarmony, float colorfulness) {
        this.numPanels = numPanels;;
        this.colorHarmony = colorHarmony;
        this.colorfulness = colorfulness;
    }
}
```

This is the script with the ZMQ logic

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading;
using NetMQ;
using NetMQ.Sockets;
using UnityEngine;

public class PythonNetworking {
    private bool clientStopped;
    private RequestSocket requestSocket;

    private byte[] frame;
    // for now only one request at a time is supported
    public string requestResult;
    private bool isAvailable;

    public PythonNetworking() {
        clientStopped = false;
        var clientThread = new Thread(NetMQClient);
        clientThread.Start();
    }
    

    public void StopClient() {
        clientStopped = true;
    }

    // ReSharper disable once InconsistentNaming
    private void NetMQClient() {
        AsyncIO.ForceDotNet.Force();

        requestSocket = new RequestSocket();
        // Computer running the server which must receive the info
        requestSocket.Connect("tcp://192.168.0.104:5555");
        
        isAvailable = true;

        while (!clientStopped)
        {
            //Debug.Log("Continuing");
        }

        requestSocket.Close();
        NetMQConfig.Cleanup();
    }

    public void SetFrame(byte[] currFrame) {
        frame = currFrame;
    }

    // Create queue of requests in case multiple have to be handled
    private void SimpleRequest(string endpoint, string request) {
        // wait until socket is available
        while (!isAvailable) {
            //Debug.Log("Socket unavailable");
        }

        isAvailable = false;
        if (request == null) {
            requestSocket.SendFrame(endpoint);
        } else {
            Debug.Log("Sending to Python server: " + request);
            try
            {    
                requestSocket.SendMoreFrame(endpoint);
                Debug.Log("SendMoreFrame called");
                requestSocket.SendFrame(request);
                Debug.Log("SendFrame called");

            }
            catch (System.Exception)
            {
                Debug.Log("Something went wrong");
                throw;
            }
            
        }

        var msg = requestSocket.ReceiveFrameBytes();
        Debug.Log("ReceiveFrameBytes returned a value");
        isAvailable = true;
        requestResult = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(msg);
    }

    public void PerformRequest(string endpoint, string request) {
        requestResult = null;
        var requestThread = new Thread(() => SimpleRequest(endpoint, request));
        requestThread.Start();
    }
}
```

This is the script making the request when an event is triggered:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using Microsoft.MixedReality.Toolkit.Input;
using Microsoft.MixedReality.Toolkit.UI;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

public class MyTool: MonoBehaviour {

private PythonNetworking pythonNetworking;
public struct PanelConstraints {
    public string name;
    public float height;
    public float width;
}

public void Start() {
    pythonNetworking = new PythonNetworking();
    Debug.Log("Tool initialized!");
    //called here for debugging purposes, this method is called when a button is pressed
    SubmitConstraints();
}
//When a button is pressed
public void SubmitConstraints() {
    Debug.Log("Submitting constraints...");
    StartCoroutine(CreateRequest("P"));
}

private IEnumerator CreateRequest(string type) {
    Serialization.Request request = new Serialization.Request(1, false, 1.0f);
    var requestJson = JsonUtility.ToJson(request);
    pythonNetworking.PerformRequest(type, requestJson);
    yield return new WaitUntil(() => pythonNetworking.requestResult != null);

    if (type == "P") {
         panelData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<string>>(pythonNetworking.requestResult);
        } 
    }
}
```

Finally, the Python server code is:

```
context = zmq.Context()
socket = context.socket(zmq.REP)
socket.bind('tcp://*:5555')

while True:
    request = socket.recv_multipart()
    print("Somethings received");
    req = json.loads(request[1])
    #Data is processed
```

As per the setup, I'm using **Unity 2019.4.26f1**, I create a 3D scene, I add a `GameObject` to it, I attach the script `MyTool.cs` to it and I attach a button under the previous `GameObject`. On clicking the button, the `SubmitContrainst()` method is called (now called automatically in `Start()` for debugging purposes). This scene is deployed in the Hololens 2 using Visual Studio 2019 (although I've tried to run it in the Game Mode, communicating with a different computer to recreate the deployment environment, that is, with the client and the server in different devices and with different implementations of the library). When the application is about to start in the Hololens, the exception I introduced previously (see screenshot) is thrown. The Python server, running with **Python version 3.10.4**, doesn't receive anything. TCP communication seems to work, since when I run two Python scripts in different hosts performing client/server communication with ZMQ (using `REQ` and `REP`), it works, but I get the feeling this communication doesn't work on the Hololens 2. But this feels very strange because I've managed to communicate the Hololens 2 with another device (using another library, `Windows.Networking.Socket`).

Comment: Could you provide a [MCVE]?

Comment: Hi @BillyLiu-MSFT, I've added all the info you'd need if you wanted to replicate the situation. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Would you navigate to [Unity] -> [Player Settings] -> [Publishing Settings] to check the Capability of your project and make sure Internet Client or Internet Client Server is enabled according to the purpose. It can also be reviewed and modified in the manifest file of C# project.

The code around the thrown exception is more like Unity generated, you need to add break point to see if this issue is caused by a failed socket connection.

In addtion, you may also refer to the discussion on [Web Socket Client Disconnecting Exception Being Thrown in UWP Builds - Unity Forum](https://forum.unity.com/threads/web-socket-client-disconnecting-exception-being-thrown-in-uwp-builds.593422/).